# Can I flip the HTTP Method from GET to POST in some form of JSP redirect?

Tags: jsp, servlets, redirect, http-post, http-get

I've got a JSP redirecting to a URL backed by a servlet just fine - for example, with

```
<jsp:forward page="/myservlet"/>
```

but I'd like to switch the method from the incoming GET to a POST against the servlet URL.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. The incoming request has to be a POST as well. Just execute the desired job in the `doGet()` method.

Please note that `<jsp:forward>` doesn't do a redirect. A redirect is basically a 3nn response with a `Location` header pointing to the new URL on which the browser has to invoke a new GET request (which get reflected in browser address bar as well). The `response.sendRedirect()` does that with a 302 response. A forward takes place fully internally in the server side, without changing the request URL.

Comment: Good point! Thanks for the response, just needed to check I hadn't missed anything obvious.